# When making a fit to data without weights, how reliable are the fit errors?

Tags: error, fitting, measurement-error

I often need to fit data which is a spectrum. And it isn't possible to have many identical spectrum from which to produce error bars on the individual points in an averaged spectrum.

So my question is: How reliable are the fit errors associated to the output parameters of said fit? I figure they are a representation of the fit residuals. And any argument that I use these fit parameter errors in most likely has to assume Gaussian statistics.

Are there any methods of testing validity of non weighted fit parameter errors?